# Python babynames project trying to validate user input

Tags: python

I am new to Python and programming in general, and would like some helpful advice on how to make this code snippet work.

The entire program searches two text files for baby names and their ranking. The first try/except statement works as needed, but the second one is giving me some troubles.

I need the user to input either 'boy' or 'girl' to determine which file to begin searching. If the user misspells or enters anything other than boy or girl, I need the error 'Invalid gender' to be displayed. As it is now, I am getting the following error--

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/Drew/Documents/CIT 144/babynames.py", line 14, in 
    if input == boy:

NameError: name 'boy' is not defined

I am totally lost on what to do next, I know I need to define name 'boy', but I do not know where or how to do that.

Thanks in advance for any and all responses.

```
try:
     boyfile = open("boynames2014.txt", "r")
     girlfile = open("girlnames2014.txt", "r")

 except IOError:
     print("Error: file not found")




 try:
      gender = input("Enter gender (boy/girl): ")
      if input == boy:
          print("Enter name to search for: ",name)
      if input == girl:
          print("Enter name to search for: ",name)



 except IOError:
     print("Invalid gender")
```

Answer (score 2):

`boy` and `girl` need to be strings.

```
  if input == "boy":
      ...
  if input == "girl":
      ...
```

Note, there is nothing in this comparison that would raise IOError, so you shouldn't try to catch that exception.

Comment: That works great, but is there a way to raise the error? I need for it to catch it if anything other than boy or girl is entered.

Comment: Raising an IOError would not be the appropriate way to do that. You should use `if/elif/else`.

Comment: So something like 'if gender = "boy" print("Enter name....   elif gender = girl print("Enter name...   else: print(Invalid....

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
 try:
  gender = input("Enter gender (boy/girl): ")
  if input == "boy":
      print("Enter name to search for: ",name)
  if input == "girl":
      print("Enter name to search for: ",name)
```

You are comparing against literals. Text literals should be in quotes.